# Need an OOP method for share variable between function?

Tags: python, oop

I have a class and some functions. In the 'check_reflexive()' function, there is a variable called reflexive_list. I want to use this variable also in the 'antisymmetric' function.
I checked some examples about class but didn't find a specific example to solve this problem.
I'll be waiting for your advice. Hope you have a nice day

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
    
    def checkif_pair(k):
        for a in k:
            if a%2 == 0:
                None
            else:
                return False
        return True
    
    def check_reflexive(k):
        j = 0
        z = 0
        reflexive_list = []
        while j < len(k):
            i = 0
            while i < len(k):
                if k[i] == k[j]:
                    tup = k[j],k[i]
                    reflexive_list.append(tup)
                i += 1
            else:
                None
            j = j + 1
        else:
            None
        print(reflexive_list)
        if len(reflexive_list) == len(self.list1):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def antisymmetric(k):
        antisymettric_list = []
        for b in k:
            swap1 = b[0]
            swap2 = b[1]
            newtuple = (swap2, swap1)
            antisymettric_list.append(newtuple)

        for ü in reflexive_list:
            if ü in antisymettric_list:
                antisymettric_list.remove(ü)
            else:
                None

        print(antisymettric_list)

        for q in antisymettric_list:
            if q in k:
                print("The system is not Anti-Symmetric.")
                break
        print("The system is Anti-Symmetric.")
        
    def transitive(k):
        result = {}
        for first, second in k:
            result.setdefault(first, []).append(second)
        print(result)

        for a, b in k:
            for x in result[b]:
                if x in result[a]:
                    None
                else:
                    print("There is no {} in the {}".format(x, result[a]))
                    return False
        return True
```

Comment: The point of classes is *usually* to provide a blueprint for being able to instantiate objects with a custom interface. Right now `MyClass` is a namespace and nothing more. You need to implement `__init__`, and review the basics of OOP in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `reflexive_list` as an [instance variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables). Just add a constructor where the variable is defined:

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.reflexive_list = []
```

And everytime you want to use it inside the function, you use `self.reflexive_list`